# Upgrade magento 2.0.10 to 2.1.2

Tags: magento-2.0

I update 2.0.10 to 2.1.2  (On centos 7 LAMP Server at localhost ) it is working too slowly. What sould I do ? make fast

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE. Your question is very confusing. Please update it with more details. Try to describe in full sentences what you are doing and what happens.